# mkdir:cannot create directory : operation not permitted

Tags: permissions

I have a strange problem. I cannot create a file or directory in a directory.
Here is the detail description:

1. login shell with `root`
2. for directory `/home/a`, I can create file, directory normally. But for directory `/home/a/b`, I cannot create file, directory, with `touch` and `mkdir` command.s
3. I have checked the permissions of directory `/home/a/b`, using `lsattr -d`, `getacl`, and there is no i permission, and normal permission is `777`.
4. `/a/b` is local directory, not mount on nfs or others.

here is the output, is there any other solution?

[root@web1 cms.ear]# lsattr -d /home/webSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/webCell01/cmsear/cms.war

---------------- /home/webSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/webCell01/cmsear/cms.war

[root@web1 cms.ear]# getfacl -d /home/webSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/webCell01/cmsear/cms.war

getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names

file: home/webSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/installedApps/webCell01/cmsear/cms.war

owner: root
group: root

user::rwx

group::rwx

other::rwx

[root@web1 cms.ear]# cd cms.war

[root@web1 cms.war]# mkdir mmm

mkdir: cannot create directory 'mmm': operation not permitted

[root@web1 cms.war]# df -h .

Filesystem                  Size    Used    Avail   Use%    Mounted on

/dev/mapper/rootvg-root     91G     24G     67G     27%     /

Comment: Please copy&paste the commands and output **as text** instead of showing a screen shot.

Comment: Which file system? Please post the output from `mount`

Comment: @Philippos file system is ext4. output of mount is simple, only one lv mounted on directory "/"

Comment: @Bodo updated the output, thanks.